# How to add security so that a modal window is not deleted from the html code of the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, web, browser

I have a modal window of Bootstrap 4, the modal window is displayed on a user's page so that it cannot query data. This modal window is displayed when the information is not yet available to the user.

When I did the test my page shows me the modal but when accessing the web code I could delete the modal and enter the form so I could consult data although the grid did not show me records.

My question is, how can I make this modal cannot be deleted from the html code in the web browser and the user tries to consult data?

The code of my modal is this:

```html
<div id="PopupInformation" class="modal fade" data-backdrop=”static” data-keyboard=”false” tabindex=”-1″>
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <br />
                    <h6 style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold">
                        The information is not available at the moment consult later
                    </h6>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">                     
                    <div class="container">                                                               
                        <div class="row">                            
                            <input id="btnAccept" type="button" value="Accept" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block data-dismiss="modal"  />
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                            </div>
                        </div>                                     
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good way to go about securing anything on a webpage.  If there's data that shouldn't be accessible, don't let it get to the browser.  A user that's going into the dev tools will be able to get to the data.

Any option for making it so that modal "can't be deleted" is going to involve JavaScript.  And if you're going to use JavaScript, you may as well set things up so that the data isn't rendered on the page until after whatever event is required.

So in summary, the answer is: You can't really do what you're trying to do.